# What is the best way to draw something over an included graphic?

Tags: graphics, pspicture

I want to show a frame containing a dog, a cat and a rabbit one by one. Totally three pictures. So naturally, I would draw the frame first, save it to a PDF or an EPS, and include it three times, with the dog, the cat and the rabbit respectively.

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{the_frame.eps}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0) % Line #1
        % So I draw a dog here, with PostScript.
    \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
```

But I'll have to adjust the parameters at Line #1 to make sure the dog is at the center of the frame. And more fatally, if the scale of the included graphic has changed, whatever between `pspicture` is screwed.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57421/21891

Comment: You could try [overpic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic).